On the simultaneity of cause and effect?
So I understand the physicists framing of casuality as follows: given an initial value of a system, say a cart on a piece of land. I add a fictitious (and privileged) initial condition, say a push. Then I say I calculate the force on the cart. And then I make statements like if I hadn't pushed the cart, it wouldn't have moved. Cause precedes effect, blah blah blah.
What blew me away was in "Part Two, Chapter one - Examination of Conditions" of the book the fundamental wisdom of the middle way - Jay L Garfield, Nagarjuna argues against such privileged fiction and concludes in dependent arising of phenomena.
Let me elaborate a bit. If I equally privilege both the cart and myself I would conclude I was able because the cart was there simultaneously as was I and we interacted with a push.
In a more mathematical language rather than viewing causality as something as irrelevant as the entire hypersurface. Instead in Buddhism causality was viewed to make sense given I am an experimentalist as part of the hypersurface I can only conclude the above paragraph. This leads to simultaneity of cause and effect or dependent arising of phenomena.
Why was the latter view ignored in the west?

Some causes and effects do indeed reciprocate. When the cue ball hits a red in snooker, the impact of the cue ball causes the effect of increasing the momentum of the red, but the impact also reduces the momentum of the cue ball by the same amount. If you ask what caused the red to move, the answer is the impact of the cue ball. If you ask what caused the cue ball to decelerate, the answer is the impact of the red. There is nothing mystical about it. Other interactions are not quite so symmetrical in appearance. If you flick on a light switch with your finger, the room floods with light. There is no simultaneous two-way effect there.

"If you flick on a light switch with your finger, the room floods with light. There is no simultaneous two-way effect there." - sure there is, your hand is affected by the energy and momentum of the switch in the same way that one ball hitting another ball is affected.

@TKoL sure, I agree with that, but the overall arrangement isn't symmetric if you take the flicking finger as the trigger of the room being flooded with light. You have to unpack what seems to be happening and break it down into the component parts.

When you consider all of the actions it took to install the light and the electrical system and everything, I think it balances out
